# Replacement theorem for first-order logic and restrictions

Tags: first-order-logic

I have asked a similar question in the past, but it took me quite a while to get to the point of knowing what I actually want to ask. Now, let me start with a theorem taken from "An introduction to mathematical logic", by Richard Hodel. At page 210, it talks about a Replacement Theorem enunciated this way: Let $\Gamma \vdash B \leftrightarrow C$, let $A$ be a formula in which $B$ occurs, and let $A^*$ be obtained from $A$ by replacing one or more of the occurrences of $B$ with $C$. Then $\Gamma \vdash A \leftrightarrow A^*$.

In the proof, a lemma that is not proved is used. The lemma says the following: if $\Gamma \vdash A \leftrightarrow B$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x A \leftrightarrow \forall x B$.

Now, if I try to prove the lemma, at some point I have to use universal generalisation in order to make the $\forall$ symbol appear. However, as far as I understand universal generalisation comes with a restriction on $x$ which must not occur free in any of the formulas in $\Gamma$.
What I did was taking $A \leftrightarrow B$, extracting $A\rightarrow B$, applying UG to get $\forall x (A \rightarrow B)$, then I used the distributivity axiom to get $\forall x A \rightarrow \forall x B$. Finally, I did the same thing in the other direction and I could turn the $\rightarrow$ into $\leftrightarrow$.

My question is: are the lemma and the theorem missing some restrictions or are they really as general as the book is saying? And if they are, how do you get past the restrictions of universal generalisation?

Comment: See page 170: it seems that the Gen rule and the $\forall$-distribution rule have no restrictions.

Comment: I have to say I'm confused. The proof of the Gen rule makes perfect sense to me when I read it on paper, but still, going back to my example, we start from $\Gamma \vdash A \leftrightarrow B$. Suppose that one of the formulas in $\Gamma$ is $x=c$, where $c$ is a constant. Then, for all we know, the deduction of $A \leftrightarrow B$ may rely on $x$ being equal to $c$, therefore, how can it be that $\forall x (A \leftrightarrow B)$?

Comment: The issue is thorny... Disclaim: I've not read Hodel. Some checks: Shoenfiled (1967) states the *Equiv Th* for "theorems": if $\vdash B \leftrightarrow B'$ then $\vdash A \leftrightarrow A'$, where $A'$ is obtained from $A$ ...

Comment: [Tourlakis (2003)](https://books.google.it/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA51) has it in the form: Let $\Gamma \vdash
A ↔ B$, and let $C'$ be obtained from $C$ ...Then $\Gamma \vdash C ↔ C'$.

Comment: [Tourlakis (2008)](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAwgCTgnycC&pg=PA169) has: if $\Gamma \vdash A \equiv B$, then $\Gamma \vdash (\forall x) \ldots$, provided no formula of $\Gamma$ has a free $x$.

Comment: Conclusion, we have to dig on the fine details of the rules; some proof systems has the "unrestricted" Gen rule, while others has only the "Gen Th". The basic effect is to restrict Deduction Th in case of predicate logic (the first case) vs use the Ded Th in the same form for both prop and predicate calculus. See [Tourlakis (2008), page 157](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAwgCTgnycC&pg=PA157) for discussion.

Comment: Fascinating. Thanks. What I get from this is that Mr Hodel probably lives in a world (i.e. a proof system) where all generalisations are fine, he deduces a lot of extra fancy rules, but as soon as he wants to use the deduction theorem it will only work if the formulas he moves across the $\vdash$ sign are closed. For example, if he assumes $x=3$, he can prove $\forall x \, x=3$, but he cannot say $x=3 \rightarrow \forall x \, x=3$.

Comment: Exactly: I have not read Hodel, but similar proof systems (like Mendelson's one) are exactly like that: unrestricted Gen rule and "restricted" Deduction Th in order to avoid the derivation from the allowed $x=3 \vdash \forall x (x=3)$ of the invalid $\vdash (x=3) \to \forall x (x=3)$.

Comment: See [Hodel, page 184](https://books.google.it/books?id=SxRYdzWio84C&pg=PA184) for the restriction on the *Deduction Th*.

Comment: Grazie, Mauro! This was incredibly subtle.